# Can't write to file in Google Cloud

Tags: python, sql, flask, google-cloud-platform, sqlite3-python

Currently, I have an SQL Database that I wish to edit locally. This is for a flask app made in python 3, using sqlite3.

```
 con = sqlite3.connect('Database/accounts.db')
 cur = con.cursor()
 cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO Requests (Type, Argument, Priority, Time) VALUES ('{a}','{b}',{c},'{d}')")
 con.commit()
```

Except I keep getting the error: `attempt to write a readonly database`

Comment: I'm very new to this, and I just can't find an answer online

Comment: You have tagged `google-cloud-platform`. Which service is your code running on? What is the full pathname? Is the file `accounts.db` located on a read-only file system? Which operating system and version? Edit your question with more details. You are leaving out the information necessary to solve your problem.

Comment: How do I get this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer because google cloud apps using Flask are forced to be a read-only database. Your forced to create files on anything but where those files are stored. For example cloud SQL or cloud storage

Comment: This answer is wrong.

Comment: No? Then please explain why.

Comment: “Forced to be a read-only …” is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The error says **'readonly database'**. Therefore it seems you don't have **write permission** to this file. To fix this error, you can try the following:

1. Check the file permissions: Make sure that the file has write
   permission for the user who is running the program. You can check
   the file permissions using the `ls -l` command in the terminal or
   command prompt.
2. Change the file permissions: If the file does not have write
   permission, you can change the file permissions using the chmod
   command in the terminal or command prompt. For example, you can use
   `chmod +w <filename>` to add write permission to the file.
3. Check the file path: Make sure that the file path you are using is
   correct and that the file exists at the specified location.
4. Check if the file is open: If the file is open in another
   application or process, it may be locked and not allow writing. Make
   sure that the file is not open in any other application or process
   before trying to write to it.
5. Try using a different file: If none of the above solutions work, you
   can try using a different SQLite database file or creating a new
   file with write permission and using that instead.

Comment: But this is not linux.

Comment: I found the dev terminal but the files I need to access are in a bucket, how can I get to it?

Comment: Which command line tool are you using? If you are using something like `gsutil`, you can access the bucket using `gsutil ls gs://BUCKET_NAME`. Please do some google search.

Comment: Now how would i go from that to changing the write permissions